# AngularStrap bs-select does not show dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I'm using AngularStrap in my project. I want a [multiple selection component](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/selects), and I'm using it like in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aymar/rttfd22t/) I created. But I'm not able to see the dropdown. Am I missing something to trigger the dropdown? I tried different values for `data-trigger` attribute, but it doesn't seem to work anyway.

I'm using Angular 1.4. Updating my question with the same code in the above fiddle.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <form>
        <label>Show in:&nbsp;</label>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
            ng-model="selectedIcons" 
            data-html="true" data-multiple="1" 
            data-trigger="focus" data-animation="am-flip-x" 
            bs-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons" 
            bs-select>
            Select Page(s) <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('MultiSelectModule', ['mgcrea.ngStrap'])
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.icons = '[{
            "value":"Option 1",
            "label":"<i class=\"fa fa-file-text\"></i> Option 1"
        }, {
            "value":"Option 2",
            "label":"<i class=\"fa fa-filter\"></i> Option 2"
        }, {
            "value":"Option 3",
            "label":"<i class=\"fa fa-clock-o\"></i> Option 3"
        }]';
        $scope.selectedIcons = '["Option 1", "Option 2"]';
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fiddle is giving a console error because your module is not available.  Make sure you are including all sources needed for this to run and you have it spelled correctly.  You are also going to be missing the bootstrap css as well.  I would review again all items needed for this to run.

This is the best I can do to show you what you are missing, made a plunker with the example code from their site.

http://plnkr.co/edit/80WaLp30ikmYeJqsbIKU?p=preview

**Index.html**

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.4.2"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-animate.min.js" data-semver="1.4.2"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-sanitize.min.js" data-semver="1.4.2"></script>
    <script src="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.js" data-semver="v2.3.1"></script>
    <script src="//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.js" data-semver="v2.3.1"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<div class="bs-docs-section" ng-controller="SelectDemoCtrl">

  <div class="bs-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;" append-source>

    <label>Single select:&nbsp;</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectedIcon" data-html="1" bs-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons" bs-select>
      Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <hr>
    <label>Multiple select:&nbsp;</label>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectedIcons" data-html="1" data-multiple="1" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons" bs-select>
      Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
  </div>


</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('mgcrea.ngStrapDocs', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});

'use strict';

angular.module('mgcrea.ngStrapDocs')

.controller('SelectDemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.selectedIcon = '';
  $scope.selectedIcons = ['Globe', 'Heart'];
  $scope.icons = [
    {value: 'Gear', label: '<i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Gear'},
    {value: 'Globe', label: '<i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Globe'},
    {value: 'Heart', label: '<i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Heart'},
    {value: 'Camera', label: '<i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Camera'}
  ];

  $scope.selectedMonth = 0;
  $scope.months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

});
```

Comment: Thanks, @James. If you notice my code, I have actually extracted my code from their sample code. I have updated my Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aymar/rttfd22t/23/) now, including `ngAnimate` and `ngSanitize`, but I still get the injector error. Thanks!

Comment: At this point I think this is just a JSFiddle issue, everything appears correct and when I copy paste your code locally it works fine.

Comment: James, thanks for pointing out that. :-) I'm able to get it working on my local. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include angular in the fiddle.

[image]

Comment: I had included angular in "Frameworks & Extensions". Anyway, I have added angular to the external resources as well now. It doesn't seem to work yet, and I don't think I need anything else to be included.